# How to get consecutive number of shots played instead of a standard cumulative sum?

Tags: python, pandas, dataset

I have a *dataset* with details of shots played by each user in the game. It is a *dataset* of snooker so one player pots the ball and he carries on until he misses and so on.
I need to calculate the highest number of **continuous shots** played by the player in the game.

Here's the *dataset* :

```
Game_id                       Player ID
5d6576aab80c990500e3ce5a        2ff211
5d6576aab80c990500e3ce5a        2ff250
5d6576aab80c990500e3ce5a        2ff211
5d6576aab80c990500e3ce5a        2ff211
     .  .   .                    ...
```

---

I found out a solution for creating a subgroup using **cumulative summation** and *shift methods* but what it does is it gives you sum of all the shots played during a match.

```py
# where f is the dataframe.
f['subgroup'] = (f['pSId'] != f['pSId'].shift(1)).cumsum()
f.groupby('subgroup',as_index=False).apply(lambda x: (x['pSId'].head(1), x.shape[0]))
```

---

For each game ID I need to get the maximum number of shots played by a player without giving the chance to next player. **How to get consecutive number of shots played instead of a standard cumulative sum?**

The result should be something like this:-

```
Game_id                    Player ID    Maximum Continuous Shots
5d6576aab80c990500e3ce5a    2ff211        5
5d6576aab80c990500e3ce5a    2ff250        2
5d6576aa35c80305060c4a32    2f7a5b        5
5d6576aa35c80305060c4a32    2f0847        6
```

Comment: Did you supply the answer within question?

Comment: No, that's what I tried but it didn't work. The output I need is for maximum number of shots played in one game by a player what i am getting is number of shots played in the game by a player.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this:

```
df['Streak'] =df['Player ID'].groupby((df['Player ID'] != df['Player ID'].shift()).cumsum()).cumcount() + 1

df.head()

                    Game_id Player ID  Streak
0  5d6576aab80c990500e3ce5a    2ff211       1
1  5d6576aab80c990500e3ce5a    2ff250       1
2  5d6576aab80c990500e3ce5a    2ff211       1
3  5d6576aab80c990500e3ce5a    2ff211       2
4  5d6576aab80c990500e3ce5a    2ff211       3
```

and then group it and get the max:

```
df.groupby(['Game_id','Player ID']).max().reset_index()

                    Game_id Player ID  Streak
0  5d6576aa35c80305060c4a32    2f0847       6
1  5d6576aa35c80305060c4a32    2f7a5b       5
2  5d6576aab80c990500e3ce5a    2ff211       5
3  5d6576aab80c990500e3ce5a    2ff250       2
```

you can check this article too:
https://predictivehacks.com/count-the-consecutive-events-in-python/